# How do the blue encrypted bitcoin paper wallets work?

Tags: wallet, encryption, paper-wallet

Via https://www.bitaddress.org I saw you can get a paper wall but with encryption and a passphrase. What are the steps of using the wallet with the passphrase? It seems the address is on the left while the private key is on the right.  So I am guessing the private key is what's encrypted with the passphrase? How would you decrypt it with the passphrase?

Comment: Please specify what exactly you want to know. In general terms, your answer is trivially answered in that bitaddress.org calls it "BIP38 encryption," so your answer is the [Bitcoin Improvement Proposal 38](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0038).

Answer (score 1):

When the time has come to spent your coins, whatever wallet software you use to scan the private QR code, will have to ask you for the passphrase.

Give it a try with one and any wallet app on your smartphone. You don't need to put any bitcoins on it.